# Unable to update case via quick actions

Tags: case, quickaction, chatter-feed, casefeed, record-access-level

in my sandbox, I have a custom profile based on sales standard. I can update case records via the detail page (even when I'm not the owner of the record). However, when I try to update such record (wherein I'm not the owner of the record) via update case quick action from feed, a pop up opens saying "You don't have permission to do so".

NOTE: 1.Updating a record from feed is possible when using a sys admin profile, regardless of who owns the record. 2.The OWD for case is PRIVATE 3.For case object, my profile has create, view, edit permission. Admin profile has view all, modify all as well.
4.Both profiles have transfer cases checkbox checked.

Comment: do you have permission Edit permission in case object in custom profile?

Comment: Please find the updated info